# How to get line by line from file and cut string before # on the bash

Tags: bash, git-bash

I have file and its content :

```
gnome-tweak-tool #(Cinnamon does not support)
gnome-system-monitor
gnome-calculator
gedit
nomacs gimp #(viewer and editor for image)
#aa
#bb
```

After merge with command of "pacman". 
I desire output like :

```
pacman -S gnome-tweak-tool 
pacman -S gnome-system-monitor
pacman -S gnome-calculator
pacman -S gedit
pacman -S nomacs gimp
```

Does anybody help me?
Thanks!

Comment: Can be done in many ways in shell, have you attempted anything?

Comment: I prefer to bash shell!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This awk one-liner will do the job:

```
awk -F'#.*' '$1&&$0="pacman -S "$1' file
```

Note that, `pacman` accepts multiple packages, like:

```
pacman -S package1 package2 package3...
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. This will output to stdout:

```
awk -F# '{print $1}' file | awk 'NF' | sed -e 's/^/pacman -S /'
```

This will output to a new file:

```
awk -F# '{print $1}' file | awk 'NF' | sed -e 's/^/pacman -S /' > file2
```

Comment: Hi: But I also want to eliminate string after # . For instance, abc #cs => abc

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
sed -e 's/#.*$//' test.in | awk '{if (NF != 0) {printf("pacman -S %s\n", $0)} else {print $0}}'
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

First remove all the lines starts with `#`

```
 sed 's/#.*//g;/^$/d' file1.txt > tmp.txt
```

Now concat `pacman -S` in front of each line

```
awk '{print "pacman -S " $0;}' tmp.txt > file1.txt
```

Hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

`sed` only:

```
sed -n 's/#.*//; /./ s/^/pacman -S /p' inputfile
```

Explanation:
`sed -n` Don't print unless specified
`s/#.*//` Remove everything from '#'
`/./ ... /p` Only print lines with at least on char left
`s/^/pacman -S /` Insert "pacman -S"at the start of the line

Answer (score 0):

```
pacman -Qqen > pkglist.txt
```

To install:

```
pacman -S - < pkglist.txt
```

From ArchWiki: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman/Tips_and_tricks#List_of_installed_packages

Comment: This is very useful. But it seems that does not handle '#'